# Change image name on upload images wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, file-upload

When I upload images wordpress saves four files onto the server (as defined in **settings->media**):

```
1 -> thumbnailsize (150x150)
2 -> Medium size (1024x768)
3 -> Large size (1920x1080)
4 -> Original size (---x---)
```

I always need the large size image, but when I upload an image with a size of *1620x1080* , Wordpress will name the image *some-image-1620x1080.jpg* what I don't want.

Can I change in any way the imagename from *some-image-1920x1080.jpg* to *some-image-large.jpg*?

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to create a function in your `functions.php` file, which will handle the file upload and will be hooked at filter `wp_handle_upload_prefilter`:

```
add_filter('wp_handle_upload_prefilter', 'wp_rename_large_images', 1, 1);
//Check to see if function name is unique
if (!function_exists("wp_rename_large_images")) {
function wp_rename_large_images( $file ){
   //Get image size 
   $img = getimagesize($file['tmp_name']);
   //Image dimensions
   $width = $img[0];
   $height = $img[1];
   //Check to see if image is large enough to change the file name
   if ($width > 1200 || $height > 1080) {
     //Modify the file name WITH an extension
     $ext = pathinfo($file['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
     //Build the new file name (remove the old extension - last 3 characters from the file name, i.e. jpg, gif, png, bmp, etc.)
     $file['name'] = substr($file['name'], -3) . '-large'. $ext;
   }
    return $file;
}
}
```

Read the documentation [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/wp_handle_upload_prefilter).

Comment: I tried out the script and keep getting an error in the image upload: http://cl.ly/image/031M2b1U1m1Y Could there be something wrong with the file extension?

Comment: This is weird...are you sure you are uploading images, not other mime types?

Comment: The $filetype['ext'] isn't neccesary, since the extension is already in the file name. That was the issue.

Comment: Still, it doesn't seem to be working. Your '-large' can't be behind the filename. You'll get something like some-image.jpg-large. The image uploads perfect but he doesn't get into the if-statement.

Comment: Seems like the width & height variables aren't filled. I also have no idea how to debug this properly, if I want to print out something wordpress gives me a HTTP error while uploading the image, so I can't resolve it.

Comment: The updated version still doesn't work. 1: He doesn't get into my IF-statement, so there is something wrong with the $img/$width/$height      2. When I remove the if-statement this is the name it provides using this string of code: $file['name'] = substr($file['name'], -5) . '-large.'. $ext; -> name: jpg-large1-1920x1280.jpg

Answer (score 0):

I still haven't found a particular solution for this problem, and a few people claim that you cannot change the name of the uploaded files, only add something to it. What I've used now is Gallery Theme plugin by Maxon in order to get my thumbnail and large-images in two seperate data-paths, what fixed my entire problem. The plugin is massively lightweight and does the job perfectly for galleries.

The plugin can be found here: 
http://wordpress.org/plugins/gallery-theme/